# How do I Retrieve a Stage From X, Y Coordinates?

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-11

I am attempting to send an event in JavaFX from one discrete Stage to another.  These Stages are not linked by any common parent, nor is one a child of another, so there is no hierarchy or tree for me to try and traverse to find the Stage.

At this point, I am trying to be able to get a Stage from X, Y coordinates on my screen.  I figured this would be a way to grab something I can use as an EventTarget.

However, I have found nothing at all on this specific problem.  The questions I have found have all involved event firing between components of the same parent.  Is there actually a way to get a Stage from coordinates?

Thusfar, I have tried getting a node and firing the event, but it leads to an InvocationReflectionException.  I assume this is because the node I am clicking on is (obviously) the target of the MouseEvent, and just ends up calling itself until it breaks?

Other than that, I have tried stage.fireEvent(), and that does literally nothing.

Here's a sample for what I am trying to do.

sample.fxml

```
<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>
<GridPane fx:controller="sample.Controller"
    xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml" alignment="center" hgap="10 vgap="10"
    onMouseClicked="#onMouseClicked">
</GridPane>
```

Controller.java

```java
package sample;

import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;

public class Controller
{
    //Just noting that it has been clicked
    public void onMouseClicked(MouseEvent mouseEvent)
    {
        System.out.println("MOUSE CLICKED!");
    {
}
```

example.fxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<AnchorPane xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx"
            xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml"
            fx:controller="sample.ExController"
            prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0"
            onMouseClicked="#onMouseClicked"
            onMouseEntered="#onMouseEntered"
            onMouseMoved="#onMouseMoved">
</AnchorPane>
```

ExController.java

```java
package sample;

import javafx.geometry.Rectangle2D;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseButton;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.stage.Popup;
import javafx.stage.Screen;

//This is the controller that fires the mouse click Event
public class ExController
{
    double cursorPosX;
    double cursorPosY;
    double mouseEnterX;
    double mouseEnterY;

    //Fake cursor placeholder
    Popup popupCursor;

    //Just fills the placeholder
    Label label = new Label();

    //Creates a placeholder fake cursor
    //This can be safely ignored for the purposes of the question
    public void onMouseEntered(MouseEvent mouseEvent)
    {
        mouseEnterX = mouseEvent.getX();
        mouseEnterY = mouseEvent.getY();

        if(popupCursor == null)
        {
            //Initial Cursor position
            cursorPosX = 0;
            cursorPosY = 0;

            //Set up label stuff
            label.setPrefHeight(100);
            label.setPrefWidth(100);
            label.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #" + "0f0f0f);

            //Create popup window
            popupCursor = new Popup();
            popupCursor.getContent().add(label);
            popupCursor.show((Node)mouseEvent.getSource(), 100, 100);
        }
    }
    //This is a poor attempt at making a fake cursor move
    //This can also be safely ignored
    public void onMouseMoved(MouseEvent mouseEvent)
    {
        if(popupCursor != null)
        {
            Rectangle2D bounds = Screen.getPrimary().getVisualBounds();

            //delta between mouseEvent and the point the screen was entered at
            double deltaX = mouseEvent.getSceneX() - mouseEnterX;
            double deltaY = mouseEvent.getSceneY() - mouseEnterY;

            //Movement increment - poorly done, but sorta functional
            double incrementX = (bounds.getWidth() / 500);
            double incrementY = (bounds.getHeight() / 500);

            if(deltaX > 0)
            {
                cursorPosX += incrementX;
            }
            else if(deltaX < 0)
            {
                cursorPosX -= incrementX;
            }

            if(deltaY > 0)
            {
                cursorPosY += incrementY;
            }
            else if(deltaY < 0)
            {
                cursorPosY -= incrementY;
            }

            if(cursorPosX < bounds.getMaxX() || cursorPosX > bounds.getMinX())
            {
                popupCursor.setX(cursorPosX);
            }
            if(cursorPosY < bounds.getMaxY() || cursorPosY > bounds.getMinY())
            {
                popupCursor.setY(cursorPosY);
            }

            mouseEvent.consume();
        }
    }

    //THIS is the problem method.  It creates a mouse event and attempts
    // to fire it off to a different Stage it literally knows nothing about
    public void onMouseClicked(MouseEvent mouseEvent)
    {
        //Creating a Mouse Event to fire
        MouseEvent click = new MouseEvent(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED,
            cursorPosX, cursorPosY, cursorPosX, cursorPosY,
            MouseButton.PRIMARY, 1, true, true, true, true, true,
            true, true, true, true, true, null);

        //Causes InvocationReflectionError
        Node source = (Node) mouseEvent.getSource(); 
        source.fireEvent(click);
    }
}
```

Main.java

```java
package sample;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application
{
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception
    {
        //Stage 1
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
        primaryStage.setTitle("Receiver");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 275));
        primaryStage.show();

        //Stage 2
        Parent otherRoot =
            FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("example.fxml"));
        Stage otherStage = new Stage();
        otherStage.setTitle("Sender");
        otherStage.setScene(new Scene(otherRoot, 300, 275));
        otherStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: _to send an event in JavaFX from one discrete Stage to another_ why?

Comment: The codebase I am working with is set up as a bunch of discrete Stages.  The thing I am working on is basically just supposed to emulate a mouse/touchpad using a Stage.

Comment: not sure I understand (_sending event_ feels like trying the wrong thingy for - maybe - a good reason). Are you aware of Window.getWindows? Then you could do some coordinate tranformations to find the one you are interested in.

Comment: a couple of comments (that hopefully will not be deleted ;) a) that fake cursor moves quite erratically, you probably want to use screen-coordinates and convert them as needed b) I get a StackOverflowError on clicking (not surprisingly, firing a mouseEvent back on the target that receives it) c) the code didn't compile as-is (missing brackets, incomplete instantiation code, f.i. for label) - so I suspect that not your experimental code? And maybe sender/receiver reversed?

Comment: Would this not be easier to do if you shared a model between the stages?

Comment: a) I actually fixed the mouse code in the non-example stuff.  It works basically 1 to 1 with movement now - but yeah, the current attempt is super erratic and annoying.

b) Oh no!  I forgot to mention the StackOverflowError!  My apologies!

c) Well , crap.  The actual code is on a different machine I do not currently have access to.  I tried to transcribe it as best I could, but CLEARLY failed.  I will fix that posthaste.

But, Window.getWindows() worked super well!  I can get whatever Stage I want to grab now!  Thank you so much!